# How can I get the current network in/out values of any NIC of a VMware ESXi host server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, snmp, traffic, powercli

I am aware that [IF-MIB](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/interfaces.html) provides input and output values for any NIC of a target device via SNMP. Recently a sysadmin compared the values of a specific NIC of an ESXi host server in our VCenter with the correspong values SNMP provides. The thing is not that they did not match exactly (because that's natural in monitoring) but in SNMP the NIC had a 0 value for incoming and outgoing traffic while the VCenter clearly shows that there is non-zero traffic on this specific NIC.

So my question is: How can I monitor the incoming and outgoing traffic of a NIC of an ESXi host server in a VMWare 6.7 environment without using IF-MIB? I tried using PowerCLI but I could not find the right CMDlets. All I could find was [Get-Stat](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-Stat.html) in combination with [Get-VMHost](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-VMHost.html).

Comment: Why not use some kind of port mirroring at switch level ?

Comment: I think that would be a mess. Those ESXi server host hundreds of virtual machines. This means there is a lot of traffic that would constantly be mirrored. But I think you have a point in monitoring the ports of the physical switch connected to the hosts. That could be a valid workaround.

Comment: It is recommended compared to monitoring via host software. There's no need for unnecessary workload. A switch should be able to handle things no matter the traffic as its throughput is significantly higher than a single port speed.